# I performed a 'first post review' worthy action, but before it was in the review queue, missed the credit

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review

Ok, so like, I'm one of the top reviewers on my 'usual' stack, and often perform reviews. That's all good and well.

Sometimes though, I notice a new question in the feed, and I happen to clean it up, upvote it or do whatever it needs. However, given that the actions I take are *before* the post ends up in the Review queue, I don't get a review count for it.

I almost always spot the new or late post (or whatever it is), then check the review queue, see that it's not there and do the actions anyway. I wouldn't necessarily wait for the post to appear in the queue as sometimes it takes a while for it to show up there.

Not a big issue or anything, but I'm often lurking in the site and spot the posts before they're in the review queue.

**Can the system automatically detect that my actions were 'review worthy' and apply them once the post hits the queue?**

For example, check this out:

[image]

- t+0 mins: Question posted
- t+4 mins: Mooz edits/takes action on post
- t+12 mins: Post ends up on Review queue
- t+12 mins: Third-party makes review, gets credit

Comment: What does *credit* mean here? That your First Post review count gets incremented by one and that you get mentioned in the review?

Comment: @Rene Yes; I've done the 'work', I should get the reward so to speak.

Comment: You have done the work and we all thank you for that but to put a claim on any events that happen in the future on a post goes a bit far. I honestly don't see how a review you didn't do should be contributed to you. Voting (up/down) is also a valid review action. You want to be contributed for that as well? Makes voting non-anonymous  at an instant, not only for you but for everyone. It is not feasible what you suggest and therefor a bad idea. Let's not do this.

Comment: If you do it only for the credit, you're doing it for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @Sha [dow Wizard] Cool, so the mere mention of credit means that you can assume I'm doing it "only for the credit", is that correct? I've put in a ton of hard work and have done so without needing or wanting credit. I saw a gap in the system and thought it could be filled. That's all dude.

Comment: @Rene you're right, I didn't think about the voting anonymity breach. Good point.

Comment: I seen same problem too, but for me it was the close queue, as sometime I check the queue, and for a better view of the Q I check the question in another tab and VtC from that other tab, but the review queue got no idea I did a VtC from the other tab. But its no big deal I think, it only dont show you as reviewer that day

Comment: @Möoz the way you posted this, the wording you're using, sorry but it reads as "I did this, I did that, and I demand credit for that". "I" is dominant. It's all about *you*. So yes, it sounds like you are doing this only to get credit. This same feature request could have been posted with different wording to make it neutral, e.g. "Automatically apply review action when action is done outside review" and it could have saved some downvotes here. Would still be declined (it is about the general concept you ask for), but with bit less downvotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can the system automatically detect that my actions were 'review worthy' and apply them once the post hits the queue?

No. You get credit for review when you perform an action within review...not when a post is outside of review or potentially might go into review.

It's great that you've done something on a post to improve it, thanks for that. But you're not going to get review credit for improving it outside of review.